# Is there a testing Framework for web-deployed Flutter applications?

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, webdriver, flutter-test, shadow-dom

I am wanting to automate and write tests for my Flutter ***deployed*** application.

I am able to test the client side of Flutter apps on mobile using Appium & Codecept.js with no issues. (Built a testing project in VScode and used the built APK)

I have tried Playwright, Puppeteer, WebDriver, and Selenium with no luck on the deployed code for web. Piercing through `<flt-glass-pane/>` is possible but super messy and doesnt seem like a stable way to go about it. I am hoping to achieve this in my separate codebase that is responsible for UI testing.

I am wondering if anyone had some solid suggestions on automating a Flutter web app from the client side (UI, and clicks etc).

From the research I have done, I have not found a clear solution.  I am very interested in what you have used before that works or if you know the right direction I should head toward.

Comment: With "testing a deployed app" do you mean "web scraping"?
For general UI testing, you could use flutter widgets tests

Comment: I can help clear up what I mean. If my flutter app is hosted somewhere, and I want to do end-to-end testing. (Locating and clicking/interacting with elements on the page) is there a testing framework or driver that can work nicely with the shadow dom / setup that flutter creates?